# Return an integer value from sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, integer, return, procedure

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TG_CheckUserLoginStatus]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (
        @UserName nvarchar(100),
        @UserStatus INT output
    )

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Does the user exist
    If  NOT (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE (name = @UserName)))
        SELECT @UserStatus = 0;

    ELSE    If EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE ((name = @UserName) AND 
                    ((LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'IsExpired')  = 1) OR ((LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'IsMustChange') = 1)))))
                SELECT @UserStatus = 1;
            ELSE
                SELECT @UserStatus = 2;


END
```

The problem is that it does not return the correct integer value

Here's the calling routine (VB)

```
Using oCmd As New SqlCommand("TG_CheckUserLoginStatus")
            With oCmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .Connection = mTGcon.DbConnection
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text) 'Sends the prospective user name to the SP
            End With
            'We are getting back an integer value
            ' 0 = Username is wrong , 1= Must change Password, 2= all good
            'Create the return parameter
            Dim op As New SqlParameter("@UserStatus", SqlDbType.Int)
            op.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            'Add this to the cmd
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(op)

            With mTGcon
                .OpenDb()
                If Not .IsOpen Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to access database", "form will close", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                Else
                    ' see if the username is valid and if so requires a password change
                    mRetVal = CType(oCmd.ExecuteScalar, Integer)

                End If
            End With
        End Using
```

The value received does not agree  with the value I get when I execute it with sql management studio.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns first column value of first row.  After execution read output parameter value for the integer value you are expecting

Comment: SELECT @UserStatus;

Answer (score 1):

add `SELECT @UserStatus;` before END in sql script

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar gets the first column of the first row of a result set. You are returning a value via an output parameter, so you need to read that instead.

Instead of using

```
mRetVal = CType(oCmd.ExecuteScalar, Integer)
```

use

```
oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
mRetVal = CType(op.Value, Integer)
```

Comment: Oh yes.  A simple answer to a confusion.  Thank you so much.